# Changing a jquery toggle's opening state dependant on mySQL data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, toggle

I have a Jquery toggle which contains an entry form to a MySQL table.

Directly below this toggle I am displaying the data in a list.

What I would like to do is have it so that the toggle is in it's opened state (removal of "display:none") if the table has no records. And of course be closed if the table does contain records.

To make matters more complicated my table is hard filtered to the logged in user, so I would only the want the toggle to defaut to the open state if there are no records on the table matching the logged in user.

I hope that makes sense!

My PHP knowledge is poor at best so please go easy on me.

Here's my toggle code:-

```
(function($) { $.fn.simpleToggle = function(opts) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.simpleToggle.defaults, opts);

    return this.each(function() {
        $title = $(this).children('.togTitle');
        $title.each(function() {
            $(this).click( function() {
                $item = $(this);
                $item.next('.togDesc').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                    $icon = $item.children('.iconSymbol');
                    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                        $icon.removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                    } else {
                        $icon.removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

}
$.fn.simpleToggle.defaults = {}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your HTML

Comment: Is it okay if the default state (deciding whether it should be visible or invisible) is figured out by PHP? Or does JavaScript have to do the deciding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's quite hard to imagine the underlying dom.

However, something like this could do the trick:

```
(function($) { $.fn.simpleToggle = function(opts) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.simpleToggle.defaults, opts);

    return this.each(function() {
        $title = $(this).children('.togTitle');
        $title.each(function() {
            $('.togDesc', this).each( function () {
                if ( $(this).children('.iconSymbol').length == 0 ) {    
                    $(this).show();                                 
                }
            });
            $(this).click( function() {
                $item = $(this);
                $item.next('.togDesc').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                    $icon = $item.children('.iconSymbol');
                    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                        $icon.removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                    } else {
                        $icon.removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

}
$.fn.simpleToggle.defaults = {}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thinking about it... When there are no records in the database the whole interface is not shown. Therefore the jayesh code would only need to check for the existence of a specific <div>. to decide whether to be open or closed.  Hopefully this will make it easier to work out for you guys.

Comment: Actually roselan... I think your code might just do it... Unfortunately I'm away all weekend and can't get to a computer to try it until Monday :-( thanks for the reply though and I'll let you know how it goes.